# How to fix usbmuxd spam in console when iPhone is connected?

Tags: iphone, macos, itunes, console

Since I've upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion (including the latest 10.7.1 update), my usbmuxd seems awfully chatty. This only happens when my iPhone is connected.

It spams the following message at least once per minute:

```
18/08/2011 16:30:25.941 com.apple.usbmuxd: HandleUSBMuxDictionary client 0x101005430-iTunes/com.apple.iTunes using library usbmuxd-211 built on May 16 2011 at 00:10:01, running usbmuxd-211 built on May 16 2011 at 00:14:56
```

I've already tried reinstalled iTunes, which seems to include all the mobile device connection stuff (instructions: http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3540), but without success.

I've also braved the horrors of the Apple forums, and while some people report the same issue, there's no fix or explanation for this.

Any advice other than "ignore it" or "reinstall OS X" welcome. Yes, I've already repaired permissions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This isn't normal - I get one message like then when I connect an iOS device. Are iTunes, Image Capture or Xcode running when these messages are being logged?

Comment: Thanks @bmike. iTunes was running, as it likes to pop up when connecting the iPhone. I've tested it without iTunes (by killing iTunesHelper.app) and the spam doesn't seem to occur, but not using iTunes doesn't strike me as a good solution.

Comment: It isn't - It sure seems like a bug to me. Even if you take all the actions like preventing iTunes from launching when you connect the device - you shouldn't have to not play music and and charge an iPhone to keep your console from being hit hard. I'll be on the chat room if you've never filed a bug with Apple - it's not that hard.

Comment: Right, filed a bug with Apple: #9976880 -- let's see what happens.

Comment: Apple confirmed it as a known bug. Not yet fixed in iTunes 10.4.1.

Comment: Running Leopard and still seeing the _usbmuxd process running under activity monitor and it triggers little snitch to show a process contacting several outside vendors that are not apple related. But Little Snitch cannot stop the process, it only sees it and shows that it makes contact ever few minutes. All of this started happening when I upgraded my iTunes to version 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved in iTunes 10.5 (141). No more usbmuxd spam since upgrading.

Comment: I'm seeing it on Mac OS X 10.7.2 with iTunes 10.5.2

Comment: @Dave I'm seeing this too, usually when I have Transmission open - I don't think it has been resovled

Comment: I found this http://forums.obdev.at/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6099 which probably explains what's going on

Comment: and in Mavericks with iTunes 11.1.3

Comment: and Yosemite with iTunes 12.0.1.26

Comment: and Sierra with iTunes 12.5.5.5

Answer (score 2):

The spam arrived with a recent update to iTunes.  It happens in both Snow Leopard and Lion.  Short of downgrading iTunes versions until the messages go away, there's probably nothing you can do about it.

An update:

The usbmuxd spam only happens when you have a device (iPhone, etc) plugged in and listed in iTunes under 'DEVICES'.  One obvious workaround is to leave your devices unplugged.  A more useful workaround is to just eject them in iTunes – the spam will stop and your devices will continue to charge.